# Oracle Data Modeler Table/Trigger DDL Script previews

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, ddl, odm, oracle-sql-data-modeler

i notice that this row inside the body of a trigger

V_SYSTIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP;

wrote in this place of the script, between the DECLARE and BEGIN keyword

DECLARE
V_SYSTIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
.....
END;

caused some problem for the indentation when i display the DDL script preview for the table.
Inside that script i see the trigger section write without indentation and new lines.

if i declare V_SYSTIMESTAMP otherwise like

V_SYSTIMESTAMP NUMBER;

i don't have the same problem during the preview.

The display of the DDL preview for only the trigger is right.

an example if i declare number var:

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ARC.TRG322 BEFORE
INSERT OR UPDATE ON ARC.TABLE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
A NUMBER;
BEGIN
NULL;
END;

if i use timestamp i have this, boby write in one row

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ARC.Trg322
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON ARC.TABLE
FOR EACH ROW DECLARE
A TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN NULL ; END ;

thanks;

Comment: i notice thats the clause DECLARE give some problems with the indentation

Comment: you don't and shouldn't use declare in a stored procedure, just have your v_systimestamp number; immediately after the create or replace section, before the begin